# export a type under #[cfg(test)] in crate A so that it can be used for unit tests in crate B

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have some crates - `foo`, `bar`, and `util` in my workspace. I have a type `ForTest` in my `util` crate. This type is used for unit tests in both `foo` and `bar`.

I defined `ForTest` as:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod for_test {
  pub struct ForTest {
    ...
  }
}
```

and exported it as:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
pub use for_test::ForTest;
```

`foo` and `bar` use `ForTest` like this:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
  use util::ForTest;
  ...
}
```

Doing this does not currently work.

I could have a feature in `util` crate but it won't stop normal code in `foo` and `bar` from using `ForTest` (unless I can enable the feature only for tests? is that possible?). I could just be careful in using it but I would like to exhaust all other options first.

I found [this thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/exporting-function-from-crate-to-only-be-used-in-tests/34052/2) on URLO but 1) it is very old (so could be outdated) 2) it does not provide a solution, hence I am asking here.

Answer (score 1):

`#[cfg(test)]` is enabled only when unit-testing **this crate itself**.

You can either use `#[cfg(debug_assertions)]` as an approximation (but this is also on on debug builds).

Comment: I tried to do as you said. I added `util` as a dependency under both dev-dependencies and normal dependencies. I only enabled the `testing` feature for `dev-dependency` but the feature is still being enabled for normal code. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: @KushagraGupta Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be supported: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2911.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this: In your library crate, add a `test` feature, which users of the crate can enable in their `dev-dependencies` for use during tests.

For example:

Crate Library:

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[features]
test = []
```

`lib.rs`

```rust
pub fn prod() {}

#[cfg(feature = "test")]
pub fn available_in_test_only() {}
```

Then, in the user crate:
`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[dependencies]
library = "1"
[dev-dependencies]
library = {version = "1", features = ["test"]}
```

`main.rs`

```rust
use library::prod;

pub fn main() {
    prod();
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use library::available_in_test_only;
    
    #[test]
    fn test() {
        available_in_test_only();
    }
}
```